# Why does K'un-Lun need Danny to return to guard the pass?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-fist-2017

My understanding is that Danny was chosen to be The Iron Fist because he won many tournaments and was chosen as K'un-Lun's greatest warrior.  He then was given a sort of super-power that allows him to make his fist(s) extremely hard and capable of delivering a great amount of force.  This gives him a definite advantage in any fight, but does not appear to enhance his abilities in any other way.  It is, for all intents and purposes, a weapon built into his body.

It's clear why this would make him the optimal choice to guard the pass into K'un-Lun.  But it's not clear why he is the only one who can guard the pass.  Davos was clear that the pass was currently unguarded, but as the second choice shouldn't Davos have attempted to guard the pass as best he could using a weapon of his choice?  Better yet, why not send the 3rd and 4th choices along as well as a pass-guarding trio.

Why did K'un-Lun need Danny to return for the pass to be guarded, given that Danny's Iron Fist ability was not overpowering and many others trained to be potential Iron Fists?

Comment: I assumed that the pass was not *literally* unguarded - just that only the Iron Fist would be strong enough to properly guard it. Additionally, it was my understanding that Danny left before he ever really learned to utilize his powers. Through the series, he seems having trouble properly using his powers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why did K'un-Lun need Danny to return for the pass to be guarded, given that Danny's Iron Fist ability was not overpowering and many others trained to be potential Iron Fists?**

> K'un-Lun. It's one of the Seven Capital Cities of Heaven - Danny Rand

It makes sense to have your best warrior be the guardian for getting into Heaven. The *fully trained* Iron Fist can wield two fists of...fury? and has the ability to heal others (and self?).

> Footage of Iron Fist in 1948.

Since the banishment of the five members of the Hand, they have repeatedly tried to get back to K'un-Lun (it is at least 4 of the 5 members' primary objective). The Iron Fist is probably the first line of defense when the gateway opens every 15 years. For all we know, that footage from 1948 shows solders of the Hand attempting an incursion into K'un-Lun.

The Iron Fist is clearly not perfect though, as Alexandra makes the comment that she has killed more than one Iron Fist over the years. I'm sure with the five members and their immortality (particularly Madam Gao) non-Iron Fist members of K'un-Lun are no match for them.

**Shouldn't Davos have attempted to guard the pass as best he could using a weapon of his choice? Better yet, why not send the 3rd and 4th choices along as well as a pass-guarding trio.**

They might be very skilled in Kung Fu, but none of the hopefuls has the actual power of the Iron Fist. Danny appears to be only one with that power (albeit, not his full potential).